# Revert last public commit made by another person

Tags: git, github

There are multiple commands i have seen to revert one's public or local commit.Is there an option to revert a public commit made by another person?.Can we really do that??.I'm new to GIT.Please help.

Comment: `git revert <some commit identifier>`

Answer (score 0):

I like minitech's solution but wanted to add just a little additional color since Git is new for you. You may have been tempted to use "reset" to get rid of the last commit - that's not always such a great idea because reset kind of rewrites history and gets rid of the commits that happened after the commit you're resetting to. Revert is a much safer - and more flexible - option since it essentially creates a new commit to put things back the way they were without losing the history.